# How do I reduce an image to a basic black and white line illustration in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to change a picture to a black and white line and shape picture.  Does anyone know how to do this? I think I have the black and white part down, but am confused on the line and shape portion. Thanks

Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: All pictures are lines and shapes, I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: What's the line and shape portion?

Comment: @Ryan I updated my question to give an example of what I mean. It was a black and white photo converted to lines and shapes.

Comment: @Cai I updated my question with an example.

Comment: That was most likely drawn.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're looking for a vector version of the illustration, where you'll be able to edit shapes' strokes and fills. You can refer to this article for an explanation of vector graphics:
http://www.ucreative.com/articles/how-to-explain-raster-vs-vector-to-your-clients/
Adobe Illustrator has a tool to convert raster to vector images, called Live Trace. If using Photoshop is your only option, it does not have an automated tool, but you can use your image as a guide and create vector shapes on layers above it.

*edit*
Reading your question again, it may be that you're simply looking to go from a continuous tone photograph to a line-art/ clip-art type treatment. After converting your file's Mode to Grayscale or otherwise starting from black-and-white, try Photoshop's Posterize; go to Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Posterize. Reduce the Levels to 2.